# Would the tag [the-taming-of-the-shrew] also cover questions about The Taming of a Shrew?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a tag [the-taming-of-the-shrew](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-taming-of-the-shrew) for the Shakespeare play [The Taming of **the** Shrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taming_of_the_Shrew). However, there is also a play called [The Taming of **a** Shrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taming_of_the_Shrew#The_relationship_with_A_Shrew) (note the different article!), whose authorship is controversial. Is the current tag intended to cover both plays?

Comment: This is at the moment a hypothetical question. Tagging is supposed to emerge organically. Why don't we let someone ask a question about taming of a shrew and see how they tag it.

Comment: @Hamlet The question is relevant to the current tag wiki, though.

Comment: In other words, there isn't an actual problem to be solved right now. And even if we did have a question or two about taming of a shrew, we wouldn't need a meta post to decide it--just work it out in the comments. Tags are easy to change when they're only applied to a few posts. You only need to go to meta if changes to a tag would effect a large number of posts.

Comment: The tag already has a tag wiki and it wont get deleted atm. I'm not really sure why a tag that has only been used once needs an entire meta post about it. Just make a decision and if it turns out its a bad decision, someone can switch it back.

Comment: I can't quite tell from that Wikipedia page how alike *The Shrew* and *A Shrew* are. Are they essentially two different versions of the same story, or two different plays?

Comment: @Randal'Thor The texts have a lot of overlap but also a number of considerable differences (e.g. the Sly story, character names, etc.). Scholars still disagree about whether Shakespeare wrote *A Shrew*.